# logplot for negative valued function

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot the following function

```
Plot[(1/x (0.01/(0.01 + x^2) - (10/(10 + x^2))^2)), {x, 0, 10}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

which is very peaked at 0.01 in log scale, to show it up to higher values, i.e.:

```
LogPlot[-(1/x (0.01/(0.01 + x^2) - (10/(10 + x^2))^2)), {x, 0, 100}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {10^-9, 10}]
```

However, since function is negative, I must add a minus sign to the function. I would like to get something like the log plot above, but with the y-axis going downwards and with negative values, looking similar to the plot below

```
LogPlot[-(1/x (0.01/(0.01 + x^2) - (10/(10 + x^2))^2))^-1, {x, 0, 10},
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0.1, 10^3}]
```

but with the right scaling for log axis and negative value sin stead of positive ones, is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you require something like the following? `f[x_] := (1/x (0.01/(0.01 + x^2) - (10/(10 + x^2))^2)); myTicks = N[Table[{10^i, -10^i}, {i, -9, 1}]]; LogPlot[-f[x], {x, 0, 100}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {10^-9, 10}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, myTicks, None, None}]`

Comment: Not, exactly, but I see the solution, because this does the work
    myTicks = 
     N[Table[{10^-i, -10^i}, {i, -9, 1}]]; LogPlot[-    f[x], {x, 0, 100}, 
     Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {10^-9, 10}]
    LogPlot[-f[x]^-1, {x, 0, 100}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotRange -> {1/10, 10^9}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, myTicks, None, None}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems something like this does the work.
Taking the inverse, just produce the negative value for the log.
Then, relabeling the ticks (but using also the inverse, solves the work)

```
myTicks = 
 N[Table[{10^-i, -10^i}, {i, -9, 1}]]; LogPlot[-f[x], {x, 0, 100}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {10^-9, 10}]
LogPlot[-f[x]^-1, {x, 0, 100}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {1/10, 10^9}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, myTicks, None, None}]
```

Thanks to Boson which helped here.

[image]